# Raspberry Pi: Reading Data from UART using Pi4J

Tags: java, gwt, raspberry-pi2, uart

I have problems to read data from the Raspberry Pi's UART (/dev/ttyAMA0) when following the example "Serial Communication Example using Pi4J"

http://pi4j.com/example/serial.html

```
    // create an instance of the serial communications class
    final Serial serial = SerialFactory.createInstance();

    SerialConfig config = new SerialConfig();

    // set default serial settings (device, baud rate, flow control, etc)
    //
    // by default, use the DEFAULT com port on the Raspberry Pi (exposed on GPIO header)
    // NOTE: this utility method will determine the default serial port for the
    //       detected platform and board/model.  For all Raspberry Pi models
    //       except the 3B, it will return "/dev/ttyAMA0".  For Raspberry Pi
    //       model 3B may return "/dev/ttyS0" or "/dev/ttyAMA0" depending on
    //       environment configuration.
    config.device(SerialPort.getDefaultPort());
    config.baud(Baud._38400);
    config.dataBits(DataBits._8);
    config.parity(Parity.NONE);
    config.stopBits(StopBits._1);
    config.flowControl(FlowControl.NONE);

    // open the default serial device/port with the configuration settings
    serial.open(config);
```

The callback-method is:

```
    // create and register the serial data listener
    serial.addListener(new SerialDataEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void dataReceived(SerialDataEvent event)
        {
            byte[] receivedBytes = event.getBytes();
            ....
```

The problem is:
I know for sure that every 2 seconds there are 192 Byte sent to the UART "by my other HW".
But my callback-method does not receive 192 Byte but sometimes 16, then 97, then 141,... and so on.

Adding

```
event.discardData();
```

after reading the event at least prevents me from receiving 0 Bytes...

This situation occurs when I read the UART at the server-side of a GWT application.

When directly debugging on the Raspberry Pi using launchpi

http://tsvetan-stoyanov.github.io/launchpi/

then I receive also some chunk of data with a length smaller than 192 Bytes, but after 10 ... 20 seconds of "tuning time" I *mostly* receive the 192 Bytes at once as I expect (*sometimes* the 192 Bytes are split into 144 Bytes and 48 Bytes, but that I could handle).

The code I use for debugging with launchpi and at the GWT's server-side is of course the same.
The baud-rate is the same for my sender and the Raspi as receiver.

What's the difference when using GWT, or do I have synchronize the UART somehow by inserting additional start/stop-Bytes?

I need the 192 Bytes reliable in one block as they are sent.
Ideas and hints (and of course solutions :-) are very welcome...
Best regards!

Comment: I have learned that there is no guarantee to receive data via UART in those chunks the sender sent. So I have to rely on a starting-signation and collect then the bytes I need.

Comment: I was insecure because debugging directly on the raspi (almoust) always gave me the 192 bytes in one block. But ok, maybe it's the difference between debugging and real life.